# Tensorflow debugging

Tags: tensorflow

```
        y1 = tf.stack([55, 0, 55])
        y2 = tf.stack([11 22 44])
        y3 = tf.constant([0., 0., 1.])
        x = tf.stack([y1, y2, y3])
        x1 = tf.reshape(x, [3, 3])
```

Is there a way to print or obtain the above tensor `x1` or `x` in tensorflow. The `tf.print` and `sess.eval(x1)`? It seems to not print the stacked frame.

Tried the `tfdg` too

```
sess = tf.Session()
        sess = tf_debug.TensorBoardDebugWrapperSession(sess, "Host:7000")
        sess.run(x1)
```

Answer (score 0):

When doing

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

tf.reset_default_graph()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    y1 = tf.stack([55, 0, 55])
    y2 = tf.stack([11, 22, 44])
    y3 = tf.constant([0, 0, 1])

    x_tmp = tf.stack([y1, y2, y3])
    x1 = tf.reshape(x, [3, 3])

    x_res, x1_res = sess.run([x, x1])


    print(x_res)
    print(x1_res)
```

It seems to print out

```
[[55  0 55]
 [11 22 44]
 [ 0  0  1]]
[[55  0 55]
 [11 22 44]
 [ 0  0  1]]
```

just fine? Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the question